# Drawing a polygon in Python with a set of random colors

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am working on a simple python program which prompts the user to enter the length of the side of a polygon and the program (using turtle) will draw the polygon with a random color that has been set using the random.randint

my code so far is:

```
import turtle

polygonSideLength = int(input('Enter length of polygon side: \n'))
numberOfSides = 5 + (7 / 4)
turnAngle = 360 / numberOfSides

import random
randomColor = random.randint(0,5)
if randomColor == 0:
    fillcolor="red"
elif randomColor == 1:
    fillcolor="green"
elif randomColor == 2:
    fillcolor="blue"
elif randomColor == 3:
    fillcolor="cyan"
elif randomColor == 4:
    fillcolor="magenta"
elif randomColor == 5:
    fillcolor="yellow"


turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.pen(pensize = 5, pencolor="black", fillcolor = randomColor)

for i in range(numberOfSides):
    turtle.forward(polygonSideLength)
    turtle.right(turnAngle)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

I have found the problem in the code is with the "fillcolor = randomColor"

the error I receive is "unknown color name for: 5" 
I know the randint is working because sometimes the error gives me 1,2,3,4,5

So to sum it up, how do I get the fillcolor to match the set colors in the random randint?

Comment: You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to simplify your code. Then I think you need `fillcolor = fillcolor` in the `turtle.pen` call?

Comment: the project I'm working on states that I must use imput random (random.randint). I have been trying to tweak the code but I still get an error. I am very new to python so working in simplistic terms is best for me

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with the fact that you are choosing a random color with

```
randomColor = random.randint(0,5)
```

but when you want to set the random color to your polygon

you specify an integer (value of randomColor variable) instead of a string  (value of fillcolor variable)

fillcolor variable is expected to be a string type with a color name value ( "blue","white","red", etc) but never an integer.

so may you please change the following line:

```
turtle.pen(pensize = 5, pencolor="black", fillcolor = randomColor)
```

to

```
turtle.pen(pensize = 5, pencolor="black", fillcolor = fillcolor)
```

Comment: that may have done the trick. however I am getting a new error:          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/pol1.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i in range(numberOfSides):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Nevermind that last comment. I figured out it was my math that made it a float. the (fillcolor=fillcolor) did fix it. I thought I tried that earlier and it didn't work but It worked for me now. Thank you both for the help

Comment: You may close that question ASAP if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @stellasia that `random.choice()` is your best option but if you need to use `random.randint()` instead, here's one way to do it:

```
import turtle
import random

COLORS = ["red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]

fillcolor = COLORS[random.randint(0, len(COLORS) - 1)]
turtle.pen(pensize=5, pencolor="black", fillcolor=fillcolor)

numberOfSides = 6
turnAngle = 360 / numberOfSides

polygonSideLength = int(input('Enter length of polygon side: '))

turtle.begin_fill()
for _ in range(numberOfSides):
    turtle.forward(polygonSideLength)
    turtle.right(turnAngle)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.done()
```

The above can easily be changed to `random.choice()` later by replacing the `fillcolor` assignment line with:

```
fillcolor = random.choice(COLORS)
```

Another way the color selection could go would be completely random, using `random.random()`, and changing the first few lines to:

```
import turtle
import random

fillcolor = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
turtle.pen(pensize=5, pencolor="black", fillcolor=fillcolor)

...
```

Here instead of a color name, we're using another posibility that turtle colors allow which is an RGB triple, eg: (0.5, 0.9, 0.1)  There are two turtle RGB triple modes: 0.0 to 1.0, the default used above, and 0 to 255 which we select using `turtle.colormode(255)`.  This means we can go back to using `random.randint()` and still have completely random colors:

```
turtle.colormode(255)
fillcolor = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
turtle.pen(pensize=5, pencolor="black", fillcolor=fillcolor)
```

So we now have two completely different ways to pick a random color using `turtle.randint()`.